# VMWare Server Console: Open Remote Host and firewall rules

Tags: firewall, vmware-server, remote

Consider the need to remotely manage an instance of VMWare Server 1.0.x. on a Windows network.

> Client: Windows 7 with same VMWare Server version. In this case, it's 1.0.8.
>
> Server: Windows 2008.

[image: VMWare Server Console]

We've attempted to connect using the server's hostname, and its IP address. Both get the same results:

[image: Cannot connect to host A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond]

**Questions:**

- what firewall rules need to be in place on the server to allow authentication to occur?
- any other considerations to managing VMWare Server remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some known issues with running the VMware client on Windows 7, but I assume you've already dealt with that - correct?

I'm not very familiar with that old of a version of VMWare, but are you attempting to connect directly to the ESX host or Virtual Center (did they even call it that back then?).

According to this document:
http://www.vmware.com/support/vc11/doc/c3firewall.html

You just need ports 902 and 905 open.